# Wordpress FAQ to display answers on New Page?

Tags: html, wordpress

Thanks for helping giving me some light to this. 
I have a FAQ that i am building for my site. 
The structure is like this:

```html
<h4>Question 1</h4>
<a>Answer</a>
<h4>Question 2</h4>
<a>Answer</a>
<h4>Question 3</h4>
<a>Answer</a>
```

I'm attempting to have the answers open on a New Page without actually creating individual pages with answers? I believe its similar to how the posts page works? 
I am looking for how this is possible in Wordpress.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good user experience to take the user to an entirely new page for a single answer. Why not utilize an accordion or some other form of show/hide functionality.

Comment: I know well the other option which i was riding on was just using a JQuery hide/show toggle. But what i wanted to achieve, was the user will be brought to a new page and then would be have the question and a vote if it was helpful or not. Do you have a better suggestion of how i should go about the faq? I saw an example of an accordian i didnt really like it soo much, would it work having a vote on each answer?

Comment: Yes, you could set up a voting system even having all the questions and answers on the same page. One way that might work well in Wordpress would be to set up an "FAQ" post category and then create posts(where the title is the question and the content is the answer) and then create a page template to display the list of posts from the "FAQ" category. That way your rating system could tie into the post ID.

Comment: Do you have somewhere i can refer to this method? Basically i need someway the voting will attach itself to the question if that makes sense. And would that system work on one page or that would use many?

Comment: It would be a single page, you could create a page template and use the [query_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function to return a list of posts in the "FAQ" category, depending on how many questions there are, you could choose to [paginate](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination) the results to restrict the number of questions on each page. As for the voting system, the easiest solution would be to use a plugin, such as [WP-PostRatings](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/), there are many others like it if it's not exactly what you're looking for.